# Install Nano on container startup?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using docker compose, I have a container that runs fine without my additional code. Now I just want to install nano upon it's startup. So far, with the code I'm using, and looking at the logs before it closes, it's installing nano fine; the issue is that as soon as it installs nano, the container exits (without error).

I'm simply adding the line:

`command: ["sh", "-c", "apk add nano"]`

My assumption is that as soon as it finishes running the command, it thinks it's supposed to now close for some reason, rather than keep running as is normally does w/out that added command, so I've tried adding the following 2 alternatives, with the same result

```
command: ["sh", "-c", "apk add nano", "--wait"]

command: ["sh", "-c", "apk add nano", "-d"]
```

Seems like a simple fix, but I'm coming up empty in my searches.

NOTE: this container doesn't have `bash`, so I'm using `sh`.

**Update:**

compose code is:

```
    gitea:
        image: gitea/gitea:1
        hostname: gitea
        environment:
            TZ: ${TZ}
        volumes:
            - /opt/docker/configs/Gitea/data:/data:rw
            - /mnt/h/Logs/gitea:/data/gitea/log:rw
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apk add nano"]
        networks:
            - oc
        deploy:
            mode: replicated
            replicas: 1
            placement:
                constraints:
                - node.labels.MainDaemon == true
            resources:
              limits:
                memory: 500M
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
```

Comment: How are you trying to run your container? (docker-compose up,  docker-compose exec, as a dependency of another container, etc)

Comment: did you write that in Dockerfile?

Comment: @RitikMishra Added the compose code to the  question

Comment: @sava128  No, it's another repo, and the whole point in this case is that I don't want to create an entire dockerfile just to include nano. I simply want to add it when it fires up. Mainly because I'm trying to figure out the solution so that I can do it to many containers that also don't include nano.  (I hate vi ;))

Comment: @RitikMishra Well, in this case, I'm using Portainer, which is about equal to doing a `docker stack deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never got an answer to my original question (to install nano, or any package really) on a container's startup without having to create your own dockerfile, but I use a ton of LinuxServer's popular containers, and they've included a handy ability to allow doing just that, for any of their containers, so, for now I'll add that as an answer, until (hopefully) someone comes along with a good answer for doing so with any container.

In any LinuxServer.io container, in the environment section of a Compose file, add:

```
DOCKER_MODS=linuxserver/mods:universal-package-install
```

And then you can install any normal Alpine package by adding the following to your Compose as well:

`INSTALL_PACKAGES=nano`

More info:

https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-mods/tree/universal-package-install